# php sprintf HTML template

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents, asprintf

I have html mail template which I want to send to my users
by php mail() function.

I'm putting this template to php variable and want to insert into that the specified variables using sprintf() function but I'm getting  this-

> Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments

in my html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>template</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            table[class="container"] {
                width: 95% !important;
            }
        }
        
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        body {
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
        }
        
        #backgroundTable {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            line-height: 100% !important;
        }
        
        img {
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }
        
        a img {
            border: none;
        }
        
        .image_fix {
            display: block;
        }
        
        p {
            margin: 1em 0;
        }
        
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
            color: black !important;
        }
        
        h1 a,
        h2 a,
        h3 a,
        h4 a,
        h5 a,
        h6 a {
            color: blue !important;
        }
        
        h1 a:active,
        h2 a:active,
        h3 a:active,
        h4 a:active,
        h5 a:active,
        h6 a:active {
            color: red !important;
        }
        
        h1 a:visited,
        h2 a:visited,
        h3 a:visited,
        h4 a:visited,
        h5 a:visited,
        h6 a:visited {
            color: purple !important;
        }
        
        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }
        
        a {
            color: #000;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
            a[href^="tel"],
            a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                /* or whatever your want */
                pointer-events: none;
                cursor: default;
            }
            .mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
            .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: default;
                color: orange !important;
                /* or whatever your want */
                pointer-events: auto;
                cursor: default;
            }
        }
        
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
            a[href^="tel"],
            a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: blue;
                /* or whatever your want */
                pointer-events: none;
                cursor: default;
            }
            .mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
            .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: default;
                color: orange !important;
                pointer-events: auto;
                cursor: default;
            }
        }
        
        @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
            /* Put your iPhone 4g styles in here */
        }
        
        @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75) {
            /* Put CSS for low density (ldpi) Android layouts in here */
        }
        
        @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1) {
            /* Put CSS for medium density (mdpi) Android layouts in here */
        }
        
        @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) {
            /* Put CSS for high density (hdpi) Android layouts in here */
        }
        /* end Android targeting */
        
        h2 {
            color: #181818;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 22px;
            line-height: 22px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        
        a.link1 {}
        
        a.link2 {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        
        p {
            color: #555;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 160%;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="colorScheme" class="swatch active">
        { "name":"Default", "bgBody":"ffffff", "link":"fff", "color":"555555", "bgItem":"ffffff", "title":"181818" }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Wrapper/Container Table: Use a wrapper table to control the width and the background color consistently of your email. Use this approach instead of setting attributes on the body tag. -->
    <table cellpadding="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" class='bgBody'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" width="620" class="container" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Tables are the most common way to format your email consistently. Set your table widths inside cells and in most cases reset cellpadding, cellspacing, and border to zero. Use nested tables as a way to space effectively in your message. -->


                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class='movableContentContainer bgItem'>

                                        <div class='movableContent'>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="container">
                                                <tr height="40">
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="200" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                                        <div class="contentEditableContainer contentImageEditable">
                                                            <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                                                <img src="images/logo.png" width="155" height="155" alt='Logo' data-default="placeholder" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="200" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr height="25">
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class='movableContent'>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="container">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" colspan="3" align="center" style="padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:25px;">
                                                        <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                                            <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                                                <h2></h2>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="400" align="center">
                                                        <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                                            <div class="contentEditable" align='left'>
                                                                <p>Dear , %s
                                                                    <br/>
                                                                    <br/> 
                                                                    Thank you for being with us.<br/>
                                                                    This is your registration Information.<br/>
                                                                    login - <br/>
                                                                    Password - <br/>
                                                                    Click on the link below to sign-in your profile. If you're no longer interested in hearing from us, simply click on unsubscribe below (or ignore this message) and we won't send you any more newsletters.
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="container">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td width="200" align="center" style="padding-top:25px;">
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="200" height="50">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td bgcolor="#ED006F" align="center" style="border-radius:4px;" width="200" height="50">
                                                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                                                        <div class="contentEditable" align='center'>
                                                                            <a target='_blank' href="" class='link2'>Sign-In</a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='movableContent'>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="container">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="100%" colspan="2" style="padding-top:65px;">
                                                        <hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#ddd;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="60%" height="70" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                                        <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                                                            <div class="contentEditable" align='left'>
                                                                <span style="font-size:13px;color:#181818;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:200%;">Sent to  by LinkedInterests.in</span>
                                                                <br/>
                                                                <span style="font-size:13px;color:#181818;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:200%;">
<!--                               <a target='_blank' href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#555">Forward to a friend</a>-->
                               </span>
                                                                <br/>
                                                                <span style="font-size:13px;color:#181818;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:200%;">
                                   <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#555">click here to unsubscribe</a>
                                                               </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="40%" height="70" align="right" valign="top" align='right' style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align='right'>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width='57%'></td>
                                                                <td valign="top" width='34'>
                                                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentFacebookEditable" style='display:inline;'>
                                                                        <div class="contentEditable">
                                                                            <img src="" data-default="placeholder" data-max-width='30' data-customIcon="true" width='30' height='30' alt='facebook' style='margin-right:40x;'>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td valign="top" width='34'>
                                                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTwitterEditable" style='display:inline;'>
                                                                        <div class="contentEditable">
                                                                            <img src="" data-default="placeholder" data-max-width='30' data-customIcon="true" width='30' height='30' alt='twitter' style='margin-right:40x;'>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td valign="top" width='34'>
                                                                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentImageEditable" style='display:inline;'>
                                                                        <div class="contentEditable">
                                                                            <a target='_blank' href="#" data-default="placeholder" style="text-decoration:none;">
                                                                                <img src="" width="30" height="30" data-max-width="30" alt='pinterest' style='margin-right:40x;' />
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End of wrapper table -->
</body>

</html>
```

%s is only in line 260

and my php code

```
$to = $validatedData['email'];
$name = $validatedData['name'];

$subject = 'Thank\'s for being with Us';

$message = file_get_contents(ROOT . '/views/newsletters/sign-up.php');
$message = sprintf($message, $name);

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers[] = 'To: ' . $validatedData['name'] . '<' . $to . '>';
$headers[] = 'From: LinkedInterests Support <support@LinkedInterests.in>';                

mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$body = file_get_contents('email-template.html');
$patterns = array(
        '/{name}/',
        '/{date}/',
        '/{company}/',
        '/{contact}/',
        '/{email}/',
    );
    $replacements = array(
        $post['name'],
        $post['date'],
        $post['company'],
        $post['contact'],
        $post['email'],
    );
$body = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $body);
```

And Email Template Should be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email</title>
</head>

<body>
        <p>
            <b>Hi {name},</b>
            <b>Your {date},</b>
            <b>Your {company},</b>
            <b>Your {contact},</b>
            <b>Your {email},</b>
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you do? Please add description of change

Comment: It will replace a signed text between {} using preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `%` so that printf treats them as literals (except the `%s`). Maybe something like:

```
$message = sprintf(str_replace('%%s','%s, str_replace( '%', '%%', $message) ), $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you would be using it like a template in a sprintf function, add anywhere you have a '%' sign another %. This process could be dull and time consuming, so there is a little alternative:

```
$message = sprintf(str_replace('%%s','%s',str_replace('%','%%',$message)), $name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe % signs create misunderstandings. You can try to use:
$message=sprintf(addslashes($message),$name);

Comment: This sample doesn't do anything special with '%'s as you suggest. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php to understand what `addslashes()` does.